# What is the equivalent of Android's bootloader in Windows and/or Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, boot, bootloader

Is there an equivalent of Android's bootloader in Windows and/or Linux, what is it called?

Comment: Windows Bootloader or GRUB......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bootloader is a program that loads the kernel from secondary storage to the main memory and eventually allows you to choose which kernel to load. In linux is generally GRUB. In Windows  it is NTLDR. For Windows Vista and later the bootloader is Window boot manager.

Resouce:

Windows
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542273(v=vs.85).aspx

Linux
https://www.gnu.org/software/grub

Comment: [Your last sentence is not correct.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLDR).  NTLDR is the literal name for the NT Bootloader, which means every version of Windows released, based on the NT kernel since 2001.  Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 are both on the NT kernel.

Comment: I'm sorry for the error on the MBR. Instead for the question of NTLDR i'm sure that after Windows Vista the Microsoft system use Windows boot manager.

Comment: The following doesn't contradict what you wrote but note that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLDR  "NTLDR (abbreviation of NT loader) is the boot loader for all releases of Windows NT operating system up to and including Windows 10 " Another link that may be of interest is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_startup_process#Windows_Boot_Manager

Comment: @Ramhound Hmm my understanding is that Vista onwards uses "Windows Boot Manager", as described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_startup_process

Comment: <<Starting in Windows Vista, Windows includes boot loader components that are designed to load Windows quickly and securely. The previous Windows NT boot loader, ntldr, is replaced by three components:

Windows Boot Manager (Bootmgr.exe), Windows operating system loader (Winload.exe), Windows resume loader (Wiresume.exe) >>

Comment: Poor sentence structure was to blame

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542273(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @GiorgioDramis Ahh nice, MSDN documentation.  Good find, that puts that  to rest :-)

Comment: @Ramhound Actually, really, Microsoft is to blame. They love changing names of things, but then they themselves continue to refer to things by old names. Often system files and resources have to keep old names for compatibility (think Windows Explorer > File Explorer, SkyDrive > OneDrive, .NET Passport > Windows Live ID > Microsoft Account, Metro Apps > Modern Apps)... and they don't update their documentation very well...

Comment: It is my understanding that NTLDR is a completely different technology from the modern Windows boot manager; it wasn't just renamed.